# Implementing sirikit in my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, siri, sirikit

I tried implementing sirikit in my mobile application.My requirement is using siri i need to escalate the tickets?

And i need to know how to enable siri for the existing provisioning profile in my app.Can we use siri without using provisioning profile?

please help me on this issue.

Comment: You need a separate provisioning profile for every extension by the time you upload your app to the AppStore. Until then I think you can use a wildcard profile. As for the implementation, what did you try? Please include code and tell us what does not work.

Comment: wild card you can directly use, else you need the proviosnal profile, with out provisonal profile you cant move ur app to live

Comment: Actually i need to use the sirikit for my application like how whatsapp is using siri. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

**For, enabling `Siri Kit` for the existing `Provisioning Profile`. 
You have to edit your provisioning profile and under `Application Services` just enable `SiriKit`.**

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps using that you can able to create app using SiriKit.

1. Enabled Siri from project -> Target -> Capabilities -> Enable Siri
2. Add Privacy - Siri Usage Description in info.plist file.
3. Add CoreLocation.framework in your project. (I have read about this to add in project, but not know why?)
4. Select your Project Target -> Click on + icon -> Select Intents Extension & IntentUI Extension -> Click on Next -> Set your Product Name and Finish.
5. If needed to set your own Vocabulary, you can add AppIntentVocabulary.plist in your main project.

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
     <key>ParameterVocabularies</key>
     <array>
      <dict>
       <key>ParameterVocabulary</key>
       <array>
        <dict>
         <key>VocabularyItemIdentifier</key>
         <string>slide_to_open</string>
         <key>VocabularyItemSynonyms</key>
         <array>
          <dict>
           <key>VocabularyItemExamples</key>
           <array>
            <string>Open Gate using SlideToOpen</string>
            <string>Open Gate by SlideToOpen</string>        
           </array>
          </dict>
         </array>
        </dict>
       </array>
       <key>ParameterNames</key>
       <array>
        <string>INRequestRideIntent.SlideToOpen</string>
       </array>
      </dict>
     </array>
     <key>IntentPhrases</key>
     <array>
      <dict>
       <key>IntentName</key>
       <string>INRequestRideIntent</string>
       <key>IntentExamples</key>
       <array>
        <string>Open Gate using SlideToOpen</string>
        <string>Open Gate by SlideToOpen</string>
       </array>
      </dict>
     </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

6. Now first Run your SiriIntent by selecting from Schema Drop down.

Comment: Thanks for your reply after enabling siri kit i will try to implement this in my project.

Do you know any sample app implemented with siri using objective C?